# Should I sign this letter or force them to fire me? What are the differences between my prospects with the two options?

Tags: phd

I was a first year PhD student and have mentioned before I was forced to quit although hardwork and grants. Now the head of the school admit that the supervisor was wrong and he had nothing to do with the supervisor which is awkward, he also confused about another student who hadnot passed his viva after years of work and publishing in top tier conference.

In to the retrospect, they asked me whether to sign a resignation letter or to be fired and asked me to sign in the moment, but I refused and asked them I will take the letter and do it later during this week.

They asked you have to do it during this week ( obligatory), could any one recommend me whether this is good direction to sign this letter as it is first time for me and I am not aware of many LEGAL stuff.

PS. For more details why this happened:

I am a first year PhD student, I was working in a new topic, I found a problem in research and then I proposed a methodology and verified it. My PI said from few months ago that it was good what I did verbatim. Then I got two grants from top conferences although I waited a lot of time to do experiment in other lab, and this lab was not happy because I proposed different approach than they use, but I explained what I proposed and how it could solve. Honestly, I worked so much hard as you can imagine, but in the same time I noticed that my PI is underestimating from my ideas sometimes and have sharp looking at me without any reason, at the beginning he didnot want to publish anything or attend conference without any reason, sometimes he didnot listen to me and I made correction for him which was critical for research, but I did in very polite way

He began to catch small mistakes in report for instance which was very trivial and inflate it and never acknowledge the two grants I got and I did other stuff for free like videos for the group and sketching which he was astonished by it.

Until I present my work in the committee which every one told me that they do it to see every thing is okay and every one pass, this committee is my PI, another professor who have never worked in my research topic and asked questions  was very sketchy and the head of the school also not related to my domain they see presentation and report no exams no other things, so just presentation and report. Of course this PI made badmouthing behind me and that what I know later and it was mentioned that I didnot do a good bibliography and he doubt the methodology although I got the same results as the real experiment based on physics approach, but he doubts. I was shocked and I confronted this PI, why you didnot tell me from few months ago when you said it is good, he lied and I told this PI, if you have doubts could you please tell me what are these doubts like 1,2,3 and what you suggested, he didnot say anyword and go. In conclusion, he wasnot specialized in this new topic, even when I am doing any proposed formula he accuse me that I stole it or from where I had come with this equation, I did that on my own, it is quite hurting because he accused me many times of any schematics drawings, sketches formula that may be I stole it, and I tell him that I did that on my own, and BTW I have never ever stole something so that can interpret his actions. In conclusion,  this PI told me your are independent  and he didnot like that and also know that I worked hard but he dont want to continue in this research this is after making badmouthing about me as I am not eligible to continue and even the committee yesterday which the head of the school told me I know you are very good and you did a good work, but no one can speak, the head of school recommended me to find another lab in different country. Sorry for English grammar mistakes and typos.

Comment: I think the question is “Should I sign this letter or force them to fire me? What are the differences between my prospects with the two options?”

Comment: @ Dawn, thanks for your help, I edited the question with your suggested one, yes exactly that is my question.

Comment: I think you're going to need to talk to someone local, who's familiar with your specific university's culture and also your country's employment laws.  Internet people are not really going to be able to help you here - we don't even know what country you're in.  Another relevant question, which you haven't really explained, is *why* they are demanding that you leave.

Comment: I second Nate's comment. Sounds like it's time to bring in a lawyer.

Comment: You haven't mentioned the country, so there's not much we can say about the "legal stuff" or the local advantages/disadvantages to resigning or being fired. In any case, this site isn't the best place for legal advice. You might be better served getting a (possibly free) consultation with a lawyer.

Comment: Resigning seems better than being fired. Try searching https://www.google.com/search?q=resign+or+fire, the first few results include an article from Monster (who I seem to recall as being credible): https://www.monster.com/career-advice/article/resign-or-be-fired

Comment: Can you please specify what happened when you quit?

Comment: @elliotsvensson  I have edited the question and added why this happened after PS. Sorry for prolong post, but I really need support to come out of this and finding another good lab is not easy. I am try to do my best as much as I can.

Comment: What is your exact status in the program?  Perhaps, would it be sufficient to say, "they are not continuing this research and they will not give me other research to do"?

Comment: I am a PhD student working on research project, I dont know what they are going to do, I have only one PI.

Comment: All I can say when I sent some potential PI, they told me why this happened to you, you did a lot of interesting work and they dont believe why I have been forced to leave.

Comment: Even what I proposed and verified is being handled a future work of some papers, I am honest with you that what I happened, but I do think that they didnot read my work and they just underestimate from me because there another professor in the lab I am cooperating with to do test, he told me will never do something and he was very racist.

Comment: We have discussed all this situation elsewhere. My impression from other discussions is that you have not read the contract in details. This is the main point of dispute wherever discussing terms about leaving & signing papers. I suggest you carefully read all clauses in the contract and learn about past events with others to understand exactly why they want you to sign some paper; what difference does it make. Usually one part will push for the most advantageous outcome for them (e.g. liberating data ownership or payment obligations). Make sure you see their point.

Comment: Here's another idea: in addition to your communications here on StackExchange, get in touch with personnel at other universities directly.  Use your personal email address.  Type the message to everybody on this: ( https://physics.unc.edu/faculty/ ) and this ( https://physics.nd.edu/people/faculty/ ).  Be really nice and not too long; the only thing you are looking for at first is someone to listen to you.  And when you have met them, tell them the details of your situation privately.

Comment: Also, go here: ( https://research.fas.harvard.edu/postdoc_opportunities#external )  Start applying for fellowships now; explain your situation and see what they say.

Comment: A few things to look for in the paperwork--if you resign versus are fired, does either option require you to repay any scholarship/fellowship or other monies that they've given you? Is there a nondisclosure statement? Or a statement about penalties if you say negative things about the university, department or professors? And so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to do so, consult a lawyer. That way you will know all of your options, not just the most apparent ones. If you have no option other than to leave, then your decision should rest on whether you want to fight/contest your removal or not. If you don't contest it, then it is probably (subject to legal advice) better to sign the letter. But if you sign it, you are probably giving up options.

But advice like this should come from a lawyer.

Comment: In some countries, there is 'accessible lawyer' programs, for those who can't afford it.

Comment: Problem is, in some countries the lawyer will speak of truths not applicable to all spheres. Suing in some regions can be awfully slow and expensive and coming from a foreigner on a visa almost guarantees it to fail. That's why international students/postdocs are the most frequent prey for contract holes.

Answer (score 1):

Monika, it's time to hire a real lawyer.  Get a consultation and be willing to pay the $500 or £350 or whatever.  Organizations like universities are held accountable for their hiring and firing practices. Don't sign the resignation until you have had this conversation.  And if the lawyer doesn't explain him- or herself to you so that you are satisfied, showing you the actual text of the relevant laws, then spend more money to get another lawyer.  This is a big deal.

Comment: Make paper copies of all your communications starting right now!  Also, do your best to write down exactly what they said to you.

Comment: All I can say,  I cannot afford lawyer, and I cannnot reveal which country! All I can say I feel lost completely and the other student who didnot pass his viva after four years in my same group no did something for him although he is the same nationality of the country! It is a clear bullying and every one in the committee acknowledge and they can do nothing, they told me it is better to find another lab in another country. Besides being alone and begin to see the world as monsters and no one support the student rights.

Comment: There are monsters in the world, and there are angels in the world, too.

Comment: Read the book of Esther.

Comment: Lawyers are not so useful in many countries, particularly in the 3rd world and dealing with academic departments. These people may be just quite comfortable in breaking laws which are not enforced (for some). For instance, in China, or many parts of Latin America.